# Tensorflow successfully installed but cannot import

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I installed `tensorflow 1.6.0` and `protobuf 3.6.0` in Windows 10 using `python 3.6.0` and tensorflow imported successfully.

But when I changed my tensorflow version to `tensorflow 1.12.0`, Python could not import it.

I run the command:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I got the below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Users\jinu.j\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 24, in 
> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
> File "C:\Users\jinu.j\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init*_.py", line 59, in 
> from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
> File "C:\Users\jinu.j\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in 
> from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
> File "C:\Users\jinu.j\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in 
> from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

The command worked when I used `tensorflow 1.6.0`, but it's not working in `tensorflow 1.12.0`.

I used `python 3.6.0`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "I installed tensorflow 1.6.0 and protobuf 3.6.0" - can you describe the installation process in your case? Was it `pip`, `pipenv`, `conda`, other?

Comment: pip 19.0.3 @AlexYu

Comment: Do you use virtualenv? Can you try `pipenv install tensorflow` in empty directory and then check `pipenv run python -c "import tensorflow"`?

Comment: yes, I tried, but still the same error. @AlexYu

Comment: Can you include script with fresh `pipenv` installation, `import`-test and error message into your original post? E.g. `mkdir newdir`, `cd newdir`, `pipenv install` .. etc?

Comment: C:\Users\jinu.j>pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.619]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: (jinu.j-Rt4SwkEn) C:\Users\jinu.j>pipenv run python -c "import tensorflow"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>File "C:\Users\jinu.j\.virtualenvs\jinu.j- File "C:\Users\jinu.j\.virtualenvs\jinu.j-Rt4SwkEn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py" in <module>File "C:\Users\jinu.j\.virtualenvs\jinu.j-Rt4SwkEn\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: Aha! So `protobuf` was not installed as dependency. Can you: `pipenv install protobuf`, `pipenv run python -c "import google.protobuf"` ?

Comment: @AlexYu I tried this way also, but still the same error.

Comment: Use dependency walker on the installed file and see which dependecies are missing.

Comment: Make sure Microsoft Visual C++ long paths are enabled on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because of the Package dependency between Tensorflow and Protobuf.
Try using Tensorflow 1.14.0

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
```